# Jinja Template - list

Tags: jinja2, jinja2-cli

Below are my `input.yaml` and my `template.jinja`:

*input.yaml*:

```yaml
animals:
  my_pets:
  - species:
      name: "cat"
      age: "28"
  - species:
      name: "dog"
      age: "10"
```

*template.jinja*

```
{%- for pet in animals.my_pets %}
Type: {{ pet.species.name }}
Name: {{ pet.species.age }}
{%- endfor %}
```

The result should be like the *input.yaml*

```yaml
animals:
  my_pets:
  - species:
      name: "cat"
      age: "28"
  - species:
      name: "dog"
      age: "10"
```

For sure something is not right on my template as it doesn't render the expected structure but I don't find what.

---

I've made some modification and somehow it work, but not as intended.

*new_input.yaml*:

```yaml
my_pets:
- species:
  - name: "cat"
  - age: "28"
- species:
  - name: "dog"
  - age: "10"
```

*new_template.jinja:*

```
my_pets:
{%- for intf in my_pets %}
  {%- for i in intf.species %}
    {%- for key,value in i.items() %}
  - species:
     - {{ key }}: "{{ value }}"
    {%- endfor %}
  {%- endfor %}
{%- endfor %}
```

The *new_output* is like this:

```yaml
  my_pets:
  - species:
     - name: "cat"
  - species:
     - age: "28"
  - species:
     - name: "dog"
  - species:
     - age: "10"
```

But it should be like this:

```yaml
animals:
  my_pets:
  - species:
      name: "cat"
      age: "28"
  - species:
      name: "dog"
      age: "10"
```

Comment: What is your output? And the ‘-‘ shouldn’t be inside the code.

Comment: Thank you @Aristotle for the suggestion, but '-' should be inside the code. The sign'-' always removes whitespace

Comment: So your input and output should be the same, right?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a loop like:

```
{%- for key,value in dict.items() %}
{%- endfor %}
```

What you are doing is to loop on the different attributes of a dictionary — in your case `name` and `age`, so:

1. you should not start your line with a `-` or you will create a list:

   ```
   {%- for key,value in dict.items() %}
     {{ key }}: "{{ value }}"
   {%- endfor %}
   ```
2. the loop will iterate on each attribute of the dictionary, so, your parent attribute, `species`, should be on top of the loop, not inside it:

   ```
   - species:
   {%- for key,value in dict.items() %}
       {{ key }}: "{{ value }}"
   {%- endfor %}
   ```

---

Given your input, this loop will recreate the same list of dictionaries as inputted:

```
my_pets:
{%- for pet in animals.my_pets %}
  - species:
  {%- for key, value in pet.species.items() %}
      {{ key }}: "{{ value }}"
  {%- endfor %}
{%- endfor %}
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you very much. It helped a lot to understand.